# How to associate the closest element in a vector to an element

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I'm working with python and I'd like to know if exist a better / faster way to substitute an element in array with the closest in another one.
Mine solution is this:

```
ls = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                           

ls2 = [0.9,1.2,2.1]                                                                                                                                    

import numpy as np 
for i,element in enumerate(ls2): 
    min = 100000 
    k  = -1
    for x in ls:
        tmp = np.abs(element-x)
        if tmp < min:
            min = tmp
            k = x 
    ls2[i] = k
```

Obtained results:

```
ls2 : [1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: If you sort the lists in advance you can traverse the sorted list and not the entire list every time.

Comment: Depending on how much performance you need / how big the arrays are, it might be faster to sort `ls` and then for each element in `ls2` do a binary search on `ls` for the closest. If one of the arrays is expected to be much larger than the others, there are ways to make it more efficient,

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the code below using pandas and list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
ls = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                           
ls2 = [0.9,1.2,2.1]   
ser = pd.Series( ls )
ls3 = [ ls[ abs(ser-x).sort_values(ascending=True).index[0] ] for x in ls2 ]

ls3
Out[9]: [1, 1, 2]
```